# Output Data to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

Can someone please tell me how I can output data in a CSV format? I want to have it so that it clearly shows what users belong to what group:

```psh
$site = Get-SPSite http://www.dev.com 

$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups

foreach ($grp in $groups) {
  "Group: " + $grp.name
  foreach ($user in $grp.users) {
    "  User: " + $user.name
  }
}

$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: Have you tried `Export-CSV`?

Comment: Ok thanks . I think Export-CSV will do the trick for me.

Comment: What vonPryz says is the start. To get an idea of you data output what do you want it to look like? Group in one column and all the users in another? How would the users be split? with semicolons?

Answer (score 3):

For exporting data to CSV use [`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx). Note, however, that `Export-Csv` exports the properties of objects as the CSV fields, so you have to prepare your data accordingly.

```bsh
$groups | ForEach-object {
  $grp = $_
  $grp.Users | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      'User'  = $_.Name
      'Group' = $grp.Name
    }
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

If you want one line per group with all the users in a single field, you could do something like this:

```bsh
$groups | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'Group' = $_.Name
    'Users' = $_.Users -join '/'
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```